# Drawing an unknown number of shapes

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

The program is supposed to draw circles at the points where the user clicks. At the moment, it only draws 5 circles. I would like to know, how to modify this piece of code so that it can draw circles without restrictions. Consider a scenario where i do not know about the number of circles i am supposed to draw. Here goes my code:

public class DrawingBoard {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    new LookAndFeel();

}
```

}

class LookAndFeel extends JPanel{

```
JFrame f;
int n = 0;
double points[][] = new double[6][5];
EventManager EMobj = new EventManager();

public LookAndFeel(){
    f = new JFrame("Drawing Board");
    f.setBounds(0,0,1920,1080);
    f.add(this);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    addMouseListener(EMobj);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    if(n >= 1)
        g.fillOval((int)points[0][0], (int)points[1][0], 80, 80);
    if(n >= 2)
        g.fillOval((int)points[1][1], (int)points[2][1], 80, 80);
    if(n >= 3)
        g.fillOval((int)points[2][2], (int)points[3][2], 80, 80);
    if(n >= 4)
        g.fillOval((int)points[3][3], (int)points[4][3], 80, 80);
    if(n >= 5)
        g.fillOval((int)points[4][4], (int)points[5][4], 80, 80);       
    if(n==5)
        removeMouseListener(EMobj);
}

class EventManager extends MouseAdapter{


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

        points[n][n] = e.getX();
        points[n+1][n] = e.getY();
        n++;
        repaint();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you show us your code, we might be able to help.

Comment: *"Drawing an unlimited number of shapes.."* Don't confuse 'a lot' with 'infinite'. For example, the screen here is 1920 x 1080, so if the user clicked in every pixel of the screen, and the app. drew a 1 x 1 pixel 'circle' (OK a dot), the maximum that could be painted is a little over 2 million. A lot, but not infinite. As to the problem of drawing 100s of thousands of circles for every screen repaint, I wouldn't use that approach, but instead draw each new circle to a `BufferedImage` that is displayed in a `JLabel`. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You asked no question, ..

Comment: .. so it's tricky knowing how to advise further.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by using 'BufferdImage'? I used something similar. I used the drawImage() method. Moreover, regarding the word 'infinite', consider it as a scenario where i don't know about the number of circles i am supposed to draw.

Comment: `Could you elaborate what you mean by using 'BufferdImage'?` - what do you mean elaborate? You were given a working example.

Comment: @camickr i meant to say if he could show me the code to do it. It would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: @HisanNaeem, and I did show you the code. Not sure what more you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)

It shows the two common ways to do this:

1. Keep an ArrayList of Objects to paint and then iterate through the List in the paintComponent() method.
2. Paint directly to a BufferedImage and then just display the BufferedImage.